# Running out of memory: np.meshgrid

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm struggling with an issue relating to Matplotlib and Numpy.

I am trying to create **hillshading** on my surface plots.

My input data is an **irregular spacing of XYZ points** derived from LiDAR.

**I can generate a trisurf3D plot or 3Dscatter** no problem. Save it, change the camera angles, colour it based on Z and animate it but for the life of me I can't get any sort of shading in there at all.

I'm getting stuck at **Matplotlib requiring 2D arrays for X and Y and Z**. My input data is honestly tiny: 376704 points, each with an XYZ value. I have converted the points to a euclidean coordinate system starting at 0:

```
from laspy.file import File as LAS
import numpy as np

def lasToNumpy(lasFile):
    f = LAS(lasFile,mode='r')
    ## Establish min values
    xmin = min(f.x)
    ymin = min(f.y)
    zmin = min(f.z)
    ## Arrays now in meters from 0 to max
    x = np.array(f.x-xmin)     
    y = np.array(f.y-ymin)
    z = np.array(f.z-zmin)
    ## Assign a max of each x and y
    xmax = max(x)
    ymax = max(y)
```

The issue is my next step is to create a meshgrid (as is seemingly required to generate a 2D array).
This eats about 50GB of RAM:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

And rightfully so.

All I want to do is add hillshading to my surface but the whole 2D array seems so illogically unnecessary! What are my options here? Is this just not going to happen? For reference my my trisurf3D works fine:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(60.0,60.0))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z, cmap='plasma', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.5)
```

Really want to throw some hill shading in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may be obsolete now, but for other users, the problem here is that you are trying to make a mesh of 376704 points in each direction using `np.meshgrid`. The purpose of `np.meshgrid` is to take the x and y ranges and create a grid. For example:

```
x=np.arange(0,100) #1D array
y=np.linspace(-50,50,1111) # 1D array

xgrid,ygrid=np.meshgrid(x,y) #Outputs 2D arrays
```

Only use `np.meshgrid` if you want to grid your data. You can grid your data to lower resolution using a 3D interpolator such as [`RegularGridInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html) and is one way to solve your problem and create your hill.

A quicker and better option in my opinion is using [`tricontourf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tricontourf.html). The function takes in the 1D arrays that you have to create the hill shading figure you desire. If you can't get this to work, update your question with a some data.